# How to update the router state on history.replace in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My react router has state `isActive(boolean)` value. When I use the Link component to redirect to different route I can update the state as follows and its working fine:-

```
<Link to={{
        pathname: "my-home-page",
        search: '?query=abc',
        state: { isActive: true }
}}>Go to Home</Link>
```

Also when I use history.push state is updating correctly bu using below code:-

```
history.push({
               pathname: '/template',
               search: '?query=abc', 
               state: {
                isActive: true
               }
});
```

However when I am using history.replace in javascript I am not able to update the state. I am trying the below code however its not working.

```
history.replace({ pathname: 'home', search: '?query=abc', isActive: true});
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Why my state is not updating while redirecting with `history.replace`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What version of the router is it?
In [History API](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/history), and when I've used it, the first parameter is the pathname (without object, just the string), and the second parameter is the state.

Answer (score 12):

Try `history.replace({ pathname: 'home', search: '?query=abc', state:{isActive: true}});`

Answer (score 1):

```js
history.replaceState(stateObj, title, [url])
```

or

```js
window.history.replaceState(stateObj, title, [url])
```

where,

1. *stateObj* can be set to `null`
2. *title* can be any title you want to show in browser
3. *url* can be `window.location.pathname`