# React router not resetting state on componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that uses the state from react router and sends it down with props to children:

```
successMessage={this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.successMessage : null}
```

But, I want to reset the state on `componentWillUnmount`:

```
this.props.history.replace({state: {}});
```

But, this is not working, whenever I navigate away from the page, and come back to it, the state is still there. How can I delete the state properly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way? Edit question to give us better understanding of how your app looks like.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.setState({ property: null });
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to change the local state of the component, I am trying to change the state of the last react router history entry.

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627453/how-to-update-the-router-state-on-history-replace-in-react-router